# How to issue a warning when package is required at runtime

Tags: emacs, compiler-warnings

How can I have emacs issue a warning when a package is required at runtime? I want to do something like `cl` does with its warning,

> Warning: cl package required at runtime

I don't see the responsible piece of code in the cl library.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it comes from `byte-compile-file-form-require` in `bytecomp.el`.  There's a line `(put 'require 'byte-hunk-handler 'byte-compile-file-form-require)` which seems to make it hook into `require`.  You can redefine `byte-compile-file-form-require` to make it warn on other libraries.

Comment: thanks! that's very helpful. Redefining that function feels a bit heavy-handed though, since it would need to be redefined globally to work - ie in the source code or somehow prior to loading all external packages.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following:

```
(when (assoc '(t byte-compile-file-form-require ((require '<mypkg>)) nil)
             (backtrace-frames))
  (message "Warning: package <mypkg> required at runtime"))
```

Note that `backtrace-frames` is new in Emacs-26, so for earlier Emacsen, you'll need to reproduce it from `backtrace-frame` or some such.  E.g. for earlier Emacsen, you could use `macroexp--backtrace`:

```
(when (assoc '(t byte-compile-file-form-require (require '<mypkg>))
             (macroexp--backtrace))
  (message "Warning: package <mypkg> required at runtime"))
```

Comment: I can't get this to work, but it seems like the right idea.  I should put that form (the first - I'm on emacs26) in the package I want to display the error for, correct?  Then, I would expect a message if another package required it at runtime?

Comment: Right, put it somewhere at the top-level of your `<mypkg>.el` file.  If it doesn't work, then you can debug it by adding a `(message "%S" (backtrace-frames))` so you can see what the backtrace elements look like, so you can adjust the shape of the element you're looking for.